# 'For loop' to arrange Numbers in ascending order. [ERROR] pointer and integer comparision

Tags: c, pointers, integer

This is a very simple program, to arrange numbers in ascending order. Now here I don't know how it says there is the comparison between integer and pointer, in all the for loops. I am a noob by the way.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int number[100],total,i,j,temp;;

    printf("Enter the quantity of the numbers you want \n");
    scanf("%d",&total);

    printf("Enter the numbers \n");
    for(i=0; i<total; i++){

        scanf("%d",&number[i]);
    }

    for(i=0; i < (number-1); i++){ 

        for(j=(i+1); j  < number; j++){  

            if(number[i]>number[j]){
                temp = number[i];
                number[i] = number[j];
                number[j] = temp;
           }

        }

    }
    for(i=0; i < number; i++){  

        printf("%d \n", number[i]);
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are comparing to `number`, which is NOT an integer

Comment: When calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: always check the returned value, not the parameter values, to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `i < number` where `i` is `int` and `number` is an `array`

Just change those lines to below

```
for(i=0; i < (total-1); i++){ 

        for(j=(i+1); j  < total; j++){  


for(i=0; i < total; i++){
```

Comment: Sorry about that, typed it in a hurry, corrected it now.

Comment: Have you considered applying your "fix" and and compiling the code that results from your answer?

Comment: OF COURSE!  i am soo stupid lol, thank you soo much!! appreciate it! it worked! :D

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. properly checks for errors
2. properly outputs error messages to `stderr`
3. properly minimizes the scope of variables
4. cleanly compiles
5. incorporates appropriate horizontal spacing after commas, after semicolons, inside parens, around C operators
6. performs the desired functionality
7. makes use of a VLA (variable length array) so the number of numbers could be most any positive number
8. separates code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line
9. does not contain random blank lines
10. documents why each header file is included
11. does not allow the user to enter a negative count for the number of numbers
12. follows the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

And now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>   // scanf(), perror(), printf()
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE

int main( void )
{
    int total;

    printf("Enter the quantity of the numbers you want \n");
    if( 1 != scanf( "%d", &total ) )
    {
        perror( "scanf for count of numbers failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, scanf successful

    if( !total )
    {  // then 0 entered
        printf( "Exiting, no numbers to enter\n" );
        return 0;
    }

    // implied else, some numbers to enter

    int number[ total ];   // << uses the VLA feature of C

    for( unsigned i = 0; i < total; i++ )
    {
        printf( "Enter number %u: ", i+1 );

        if( 1 != scanf( "%d", &number[i] ) )
        {
            perror( "scanf for a number failed" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, scanf successful
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < (total - 1); i++ )
    {
        for( int j = (i+1); j < total; j++ )
        {
            if( number[i] > number[j] )
            {
                int temp  = number[i];
                number[i] = number[j];
                number[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for( unsigned i = 0; i < total; i++ )
    {
        printf("%d \n", number[i]);
    }

    return 0;
} // end function: main
```